# Overloading non-member arithmetic for class templates

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload operator* to work on a class template instantiated with different types but am getting a "too many template parameter lists" from the compiler. Here is my function implementation:

```
template <typename T>
template <typename E>
inline Vec2<T> operator*(Vec2<T> lhs, Vec2<E>& rhs)
{
   lhs *= rhs;
   return lhs;
}

template <typename T>
template <typename E>
inline Vec2<T> operator*(Vec2<T> lhs, E scalar)
{
    lhs.x *= scalar;
    lhs.y *= scalar;
    return lhs;
}
```

and here is the use case I would use it for:

```
Vec2<float> scale(0.5, 0.8);
Vec2<short> value(50, 100);

Vec2<short> result = value * scale;
// value should now equal (25, 80)
```

Comment: How are the functions declared?

Comment: Also, are are you sure you want a `Vec2<T>` as the result?  What if `E` is a floating point type and `T` is not?

Comment: That is my use case. I'm using it for relative positioning in a screen coordinate system. I'm multiplying screen size by a floating point to get scaled coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the syntax you have used is incorrect.

```
template <typename T>
template <typename E>
//...
```

Is only used when you are defining a template member of a template class, which is not your case. In your case, you should simply use

```
template <typename T, typename E> Vec2<T> operator*(Vec2<T> lhs, Vec2<E>& rhs)
```

Comment: Thank you. Turns out I already tried that, but assumed the error output from the compiler was due to this syntax as well. However it was related to another function that wasn't defined.